# Perl reading from a file and writing to another using print and inderect handler

Tags: perl, printing

I have a file called malwareip.txt with a list as IP :

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

I need to read from this file and create another file (query.txt) so that the final results be:

```
ip.dst=1.1.1.1 || ip.dst=2.2.2.2
```

I have created the following script. .However I see a `||` in the first line as under:

```
||ip.dst=1.1.1.1 
||ip.dst=2.2.2.2
```

Why I'm getting a `||` before the `ip.dst=1.1.1.1`?

See my script below. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename="malwareip.txt";
open (my $ip, "<" , $filename) || die ("Can't open file malwareip.txt");

my $outputfile="query.txt";
open (my $out, ">" , $outputfile) || die ("CAN'T OPEN FILE  query.txt");

my $OR="||";
while ( <$ip> ) {
    next if  (/^$/); 
    printf $out "ip.dst=$_$OR";
}

close $out;
close $ip;
```

Comment: Do you need to `chomp` your input lines?

Comment: Do this: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; ... print Dumper $_;` (put the print statement inside the while loop. Post the output in the question using the `edit` button.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Yes, he does, but that would not explain why || ends up at the start of the first string. A windows line ending might explain an overwrite, but not prepending it. The output does not make sense, the OP has made some kind of mistake when reporting it.

Comment: I'll never know why people post a question and then just abandon it for hours.

Comment: `Don't fall into the trap of using a "printf" when a simple "print" would do. The "print" is more efficient and less error prone.` --perldoc -f printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're missing `chomp`.
- You're printing `||` every time your print, even though you want one less.
- You might have CRLF line endings on a system which expects LF line endings. `s/\s+\z//` will chomp off both LF and CRLF line endings.

```
my $OR = '';
while ( <$ip> ) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    next if /^$/; 
    print $out "${OR}ip.dst=$_";
    $OR = ' || ';
}

print $out "\n";
```

---

Note the use of `print` rather than `printf`. `printf` expects its first argument to be a format parameter.

```
print $out "${OR}ip.dst=$_";          # ok
printf $out "%s", "${OR}ip.dst=$_";   # ok
printf $out "%sip.dst=%s", $OR, $_;   # ok
printf $out "${OR}ip.dst=$_";         # Not really ok
```

Comment: Thanks to every one for your answers. I will look to your answer  and get back to you guys  with the right solution. The OS is UBUNTU.

Comment: I used a variation of this solution to get the result I wanted as under:

Comment: I used a  variation of your answer to get the result I wanted. Thanks to you and to @TLP

Answer (score 2):

Your current output does not make sense, because you cannot get the `||` at the start of the output unless you print it there. Not even if you happen to have blank lines in your file, because it would still print `ip.dst=` before that blank line. So, you must be mistaken about getting that output, or about having that code.

Because you forgot to `chomp` your input, you would normally get output like this

```
ip.dst=1.1.1.1
||ip.dst=2.2.2.2
||
```

If you have non-standard line endings, such as using a file with CR `\r`, then all your lines would get overwritten, but you would get only one line of output: The last one.

```
||ip.dst=2.2.2.2
```

So your output makes no sense, and it cannot be explained until you supply more information.

If I were to do something like this, I would do:

```
perl -lwe 'chomp(@a = <>); print join "||", grep /\S/, @a;' malwareip.txt > query.txt
```

Comment: For some unknown reason I was getting the above output. However a took a seond look and as you said the output I was normally getting was exactly the same you showed above..So thank you so much for your clarification